# HashMap filled with String and other HashMap doesn't get populated

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

So I'm trying to fill a HashMap> but when I debug I see that my HashMap "gegevens" fills without a problem but my main HashMap "events" doesn't. I'm filling my HashMap with JSON data but this works according to the debugger. It's only my events HashMap that stays empty. This is the method that I use:

```
private HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> events = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();

public class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
            String channel = object.getString("channel");
            JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(channel);
            JSONArray item = object2.getJSONArray("item");
            for(int i = 0; i < item.length();i++)
            {
                HashMap<String,String> gegevens = new HashMap<String,String>();

                JSONObject object3 = item.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject objTitle = object3.getJSONObject("title");
                String title = objTitle.getString("@text");

                JSONObject objLink = object3.getJSONObject("link");
                String link = objLink.getString("@text");

                JSONObject objDescription = object3.getJSONObject("description");
                String description = objDescription.getString("@text");

                JSONObject objPubDate = object3.getJSONObject("pubDate");
                String pubDate = objPubDate.getString("@text");

                JSONObject objCreator = object3.getJSONObject("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator");
                String creator = objCreator.getString("@text");

                JSONObject objGuid = object3.getJSONObject("guid");
                String guid = objGuid.getString("@text");

                gegevens.put("link",link);
                gegevens.put("description",description);
                gegevens.put("pubDate",pubDate);
                gegevens.put("creator",creator);
                gegevens.put("guid",guid);

                events.put(title,gegevens);


            }



        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong but I'm pretty new and it's the first time that I use a HashMap inside a HashMap so I think there's a big chance my mistake lies over there. I have to be able to use the events HashMap in another class.

This code is inside my bigger MainActivity.Java class. I'm trying to pass my events HashMap to another frame. I did this by making a getter where I first let it execute the ReadJSONFeedTask() and than return the events HashMap like this:

```
public HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> getEvents()
    {
        new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://data.kortrijk.be/nieuws/rss.json?%2Fkortrijk%2F%2Fnieuws%2Frss=");
        return events;
    }
```

In my HomeFragment.java I'm trying to access the HashMap in the OnCreateView like this:

```
package com.example.arno.eventaris.Fragment;


import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



import com.example.arno.eventaris.Activity.JSONActivity;
import com.example.arno.eventaris.Activity.MainActivity;
import com.example.arno.eventaris.Error.ErrorJason;
import com.example.arno.eventaris.R;

import java.util.HashMap;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).ExecuteJson();
        HashMap events =((MainActivity)getActivity()).getEvents();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



    }


}
```

Comment: There is in general no problem of putting a hashmap as the value of another hashmap. Your problem has to lie somewhere else. Do you see any exceptions that are printed out to the console?

Comment: No the only thing that I see is that the length of the events HashMap stays 0 during the loop and when the loop starts over the events variable disappears again.

Comment: Is it possible that my events does get filled with the data but empties itself immediatly after the loop starts over?

Comment: Where is your `events` variable exactly defined? In your code sample, it is above the class (which can't be). Is it defined within the class as a member variable?

Comment: This is only a piece of my code, all of this takes place in my MainActivity.Java Class which is much larger. I declared it inside my MainAcitivity so I could use it in different methods.

Comment: I did a quick test: When I declare the HashMap as a member variable of the class `ReadJSONFeedTask`, everything works as you wuold like it to have. So I guess there must be someone else accessing the map and resetting it / modifying it. You said: "And when the loop starts over the events variable disappears again" - In your debugging session? That sounds to me as if the variable `events` were block scoped, i.e defined where the gegevens hashmap is defined.

Comment: By the way, I am no Android expert, but you seem to be accessing the events variable from a background thread (AsyncTask). You might also run into concurrency problems here.

Comment: I'm accessing it like this because a JSON tutorial showed me this way. I added some code to my question btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your HashMap. It's been a while since i used AsyncTask but if I remember correctly the reason you get an empty HashMap is because by the time the line `return events;` in your `getEvents` method is called your asynctask is not yet finished (the `onPostExcecute`is not yet called). So the `getEvents` method will return the new HashMap *events* and not the filled HashMap.

That is the reason you use an AsyncTask: to prevent the program to wait for whatever code must be run.

You have to tell your *MainActivity* when the asynctask is finished before you try to access the *events* HashMap.

For example u can do the following:

```
public void getEvents()
    {
        new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://data.kortrijk.be/nieuws/rss.json?%2Fkortrijk%2F%2Fnieuws%2Frss=");
    }
```

Then at the end of onPostExcecute

```
MainActivity.this.doSomethingWithEvents();
```

And create a `doSomethingWithEvents()` method in MainActivty where you use the (now filled) events HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

well i tried your code with the following string

`"{"channel":{"item":[{"title":{"@text":"testTitle"},"link":{"@text":"testlink"},"description":{"@text":"testdescription"},"pubDate":{"@text":"testPubDate"},"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator":{"@text":"testCreator"},"guid":{"@text":"testguid"}}]}}"`
and it seems to be working.

But You said you want to use events HashMap in another class,How are you passing events HashMap to the other Class. Can you provide some more information.

Comment: @HeadachePanda so in your getevents you are calling a async task and then returning your hashmap which means after creating a new thread you are just continuing the process flow which is why your HashMap is not getting populated ideally you should return your map  in you AsyncTask's onPostExecuteMethod and have to let the process wait or else create a callback Mechanism Using Some Interfaces.

Comment: It seems like it's impossible to return something in the onPostExecute method. It says: "Refactoring cannot be performed, file c/users/...../AsyncTask.class is located in a jar file."

Comment: ok probably i would have to try that with your context, but other alternative would be to call a method in your main activity which can send  a callback to your fragment class after you have processed your JSON. or if this Async Task only limits to the Fragment, how about executing the Async Task from your Fragment rather than in your activity

Comment: It was indeed because of the Async Task @ThomasS explained me how to solve it properly. Thanks for the help.